# Trigger animation of a text block according to its BG color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have 2 text blocks which are filled with solid colors either green or red.

I have designed the style for the text blocks in the xaml itself. Now my issue is I need to animate the text block if the color is red. If the color is green there is no need of animation. Currently the animation is started for 2 text blocks irrespective of the color.(On window loaded event)

I tried using data triggers like checking the color of the text block and then start the story board. But it doesn't work anyway.

Please refer the code below and suggest me a solution for the conditional animation according to its BG color in the XAML itself, since I prefer not to right any code for this inside the viewmodel.

```
<Style x:Key="StatusTextStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"></Setter>
    <Style.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="flashAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimation AutoReverse="True"
                             Duration="0:0:0.5"
                             From="1"
                             RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             To="0" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Name="flash" Storyboard="{StaticResource flashAnimation}" />
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I clearly understand you want to animate `TextBlockes` with `Red` `Background`. So You can use `Trigger` for that.

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Background" Value="Red">
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard Name="flash" Storyboard="{StaticResource flashAnimation}" />
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: This worked fine. I think I have tried this before. But maybe due to some mistake in code, it did not work. Thanks a lot anyway.